# How can i add custom field in user registration asp.net boilerplate

Tags: asp.net-identity, aspnetboilerplate

I am using aspnet boilerplate template. In that inbuilt registration consist for some default fields only. How can i add new custom fields, so that when user registers they want to enter that also?

```
public class User : AbpUser<User>
```

if i create a attribute in this class it will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps:

## For .NET Core 2.0 + Angular

1. Create a property in `User`.
2. Add the property in [`RegisterInput`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/63f6e3b6147b6df7a08b09a53dad562c57dac17c/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Application/Authorization/Accounts/Dto/RegisterInput.cs#L33).
3. Add the form field in [`register.component.html`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/49f53ee5e34573ca12a1e334da26f94e4b19385d/angular/src/account/register/register.component.html#L40).
4. Bind the property in [`AccountAppService`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/63f6e3b6147b6df7a08b09a53dad562c57dac17c/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Application/Authorization/Accounts/AccountAppService.cs#L45)'s `Register` method:

   ```
   user.MyProperty = input.MyProperty;
   ```

## For .NET Core 2.0 + MVC

1. Create a property in `User`.
2. Add the property in [`RegisterViewModel`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/63f6e3b6147b6df7a08b09a53dad562c57dac17c/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/Models/Account/RegisterViewModel.cs#L29).
3. Add the form field in [`Register.cshtml`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/a56329c5ba28d0404cb5429a1f585c4bb6317420/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/Views/Account/Register.cshtml#L74).
4. Bind the property in [`AccountController`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/9b2a86179c2b8cb228ddf29c4fa3b3ba4eb61107/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L190)'s `Register` method:

   ```
   user.MyProperty = model.MyProperty;
   ```

Comment: thanks for the instant reply aaron, and another thing i am using angular template  with ,net.core 2.0

Comment: An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Invalid column name 'UserType'. when i tried to add property in User class in .core

Comment: when trying to add-migration it is showing this error

Comment: no it is not in database. when trying to add-migration it is showing this error

Comment: [DefaultValue(1)]
 public byte UserType { get; set; }

Comment: Can you try `public byte UserType { get; set; } = 1;`?

Comment: An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Invalid column name 'UserType'.

Comment: Can you try `public virtual byte UserType { get; set; }`?

Comment: same error is there An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Invalid column name 'UserType'.

Comment: leave it, thanks for your time. i solved it by adding another table to store usertype and other details and save it on register

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158754/discussion-between-nighil-and-aaron).

Comment: i post another question regarding email sending https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236426/email-sending-in-aspnetboiler-template-not-working